# Get info from Apple push notification feedback

Tags: php, ios, curl, apple-push-notifications

I want to get feedback from apple push notification with curl(PHP or Linux).
I find this code for sending push notification

```
<?php
$url = 'https://feedback.push.apple.com:2196';
$cert = 'Cert.pem';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "passphrase");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"device_tokens": ["XXXX"], "aps": {"alert": "test message one!"}}');
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

**Feedback Service**

Apple provide a feedback service which you are supposed to occasionally poll. This will ***provide a list of deviceTokens that were previously but are no longer valid, such as if the user has uninstalled your iPhone application***. You can then remove the deviceToken from your database so you do not communicate with an invalid device.

I need a PHP script to get this list from Apple feedback service.

Thanks

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @BasvanStein   This code have not give me any result. I only need to get feedback from apple with a PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
<?php

    $apnsCert = 'Your_Certificate_File.pem'; //Put your Certificate_PATH/Certificate_File.pem Here

    $streamContext = stream_context_create(); //Creates a stream context 

    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);//Sets option for a stream | For more information please see this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-option.php 

    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false); //Sets option for a stream

    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196', $error, 

    $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext); //Open Internet or Unix domain socket connection

    echo 'error=' . $error . "<br />";  //Show error number

    echo 'errorString=' . $errorString . "<br />"; //Show error string

    $result = fread($apns, 38); // Binary-safe file read and store in $result

    $unpacked = unpack("N1timestamp/n1length/H*devtoken", $result);//Get token from apple APNS

    echo 'Token is' ;print_r($unpacked); // Show token and can be replace with database update commands

    fclose($apns);
```

Comment: Can you put comments on your code? Try to make it more didactic by using blank lines to separate logical blocks, like configuration, reading and printing to page.

Comment: Please see comments now
Thanks